# Does ⌊1/⌋∈Θ(1/) or to Ω(log)

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, big-o-notation

⌊1/⌋ - represents the floor function Does the floor or ceiling function affect the complexity under which a function falls?

```
⌊1/⌋∈Θ(1/) or to Ω(log)
```

Found this interesting question in a Cornell paper

Thanks

Comment: Where did you find it? I highly doubt any real paper would have anything to do with this function...

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those. For $n>1$, $\lfloor\frac{1}{n}\rfloor=0$. Hence, $\lfloor\frac{1}{n}\rfloor=0=O(0)$.

Also, you can easily rule out $\Omega(\log(n))$ since $\log$ is an increasing to infinity, while $\frac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing function.

Comment: "Also, you can easily rule out $\Omega(\log(n))$ since $\log$ is an increasing function, while $1/n$ is a decreasing function."

As stated, the argument is false, as you can have $f$ increasing and $g$ decreasing such that $g=\Omega(f)$ (e.g. $f(n)=2-1/n$ and $g(n)=2+1/n$).

I'm guessing you meant "increasing to infinity", or something of the sort?

Comment: @integrator yes

Comment: At this point we get into hairsplitting. But calculating floor(1/n) requires checking whether n = 1 or not, so it's not O(0), it's only O(1). floor(1/2n) would _always_ be zero.